# Library for a local encrypted wallet

Tags: wallets, signature, encryption

Is there any wallet/library that restricts access to a private key through encryption, but also allows certain actions to be performed by default, such as signing messages?

I would like to have code running on some web app that will generate signatures for incoming requests. As an additional security feature, I thought it could be helpful to have a software wallet that doesn't openly expose the private key (like ethers), but still allows signature requests to be made. This wallet would work in a similar way to how MetaMask works in the browser (no way to access the private keys), although the requests should be auto-approved if deemed valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any wallet/library that restricts access to a private key through encryption, but also allows certain actions to be performed by default, such as signing messages?

Such thing does not exist.